# Monitor Apache Storm heartbeats / State: :disallowed

Tags: java, monitoring, apache-storm, cloudera, bigdata

Is it possible to monitor the heartbeat-events Apache Storm sends to the nimbus?

I'm currently encountering an issue where my workers get seemingly randomly re-assigned, albeit we don't see any obvious spikes in CPU, RAM, I/O or network usage across the cluster which might indicate a bottleneck. The only way I was able to monitor this was when checking the supervisor.log file (`Shutting down and clearing id xxx. Current supervisor time: 123. State: :disallowed, Heartbeat: { ... }`) and misbehavior in the application's results. No errors in the storm UI and no stacktraces in the worker logs (such as out of memory or anything else).

Running Storm 0.10 on a small 4-node cluster w/ ~12 workers and ~650 executors. The max JVM ram / childopts setting for the workers is 4096MiB, which should not render funny results w/ the GC.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, task heartbeat is being done with writing their built-in metrics to Zookeeper, and Nimbus reads them from Zookeeper.

When there're too many tasks in Storm cluster, it can occur heavy write to ZK, which makes ZK overloaded, resulting in writing / reading heartbeat not on time. So you need to monitor Zookeeper and take appropriate action when you found ZK is the bottleneck.